# Creating an interval in for frequency table in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe I've created in the form

```
FREQ       CNT
0           5
1           20
2           1000
3           3
4           3

I want to further group my results to be in the following form:

CUT    CNT
0+1     25
2+3     1003
4+5     ...
.....
```

I've tried using the between and cut functions in dplyr but it just adds a new interval column to my dataframe can anyone give me a good indication as to where to go to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(id  = 1:n()) %>%
  mutate(new_freq = ifelse(id %% 2 != 0, paste0(FREQ, "+", lead(FREQ, 1)), paste0(lag(FREQ, 1), "+", FREQ)))

df <- df %>%
  group_by(new_freq) %>%
  mutate(new_cnt = sum(CNT)) 

unique(df[, 4:5])

# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   new_freq [2]
#  new_freq  new_cnt
#  <chr>      <int>
#1 0+1           25
#2 2+3         1003
```

## data

```
df <- structure(list(FREQ = 0:3, CNT = c(5L, 20L, 1000L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks for that very helpful, how would I modify it if I wanted to group say in 10s and 20s rather than 2s

Answer (score 1):

A non-elegant solution using `dplyr`... probably a better way to do this.

```
dat <- data.frame(FREQ = c(0,1,2,3,4), CNT = c(5,20,1000, 3, 3))

dat2 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(index = 0:(nrow(dat)-1)%/%2) %>% 
  group_by(index)

dat2 %>%
  summarise(new_CNT = sum(CNT)) %>%
  left_join(dat2 %>% 
              mutate(CUT = paste0(FREQ[1], "+", FREQ[2])) %>% 
              distinct(index, CUT),
            by = "index") %>% 
  select(-index)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  new_CNT CUT  
    <dbl> <chr>
1      25 0+1  
2    1003 2+3  
3       3 4+NA
```

Comment: Thanks for that its helpful to see two ways of doing it